# Sound messed up in Starcraft. What's the deal?

Tags: linux-mint, audio

I'm trying to run Starcraft through Wine.  The sound is all distorted, as if it were playing underwater.  Then, about 10 minutes into the game the sound is perfect for 1-2 seconds.  Then, there's no sound at all.

I have another sound issue which might give a hint.  If I'm playing a video on YouTube, and I open vlc to play a movie, the movie will have no sound.  If I close Chrome, the sound then starts on the video.

vlc often gives me this error when I do this:

> Audio output failed: The audio device "sysdefault:CARD=SB" could not
>   be used: Device or resource busy.

I have no idea where to start.  I've looked through a bunch of forums where people have similar problems but, after pages of querying, no solution is found.

If you need more info, please ask in the comments and I will update this question asap.

Comment: To be clear, you're running Chrome and VLC native, or via wine?

Comment: Yes I'm running Chrome and VLC native, in Linux Mint 14.